# How do you find the factorial of a decimal or negative number and what does it show us?

Tags: factorial

I know that you can find the factorial of positive integers where n!= n(n-1)...2 x 1. However, what if you want to find the factorial of a negative integer or a decimal? I tried to do it on my calculator and it gave an answer however, I wasn't able to understand how they calculator got the answers.

I did some research and came across the gamma function which supposedly allowed you to solve such questions. However, I found it very hard to understand and still don't see the purpose of finding the factorial of a negative integers or decimals.

Help would be appreciated.

Thank you :)

Comment: The factorial is an integer function, but look up something called the gamma function ($\Gamma$.) It is the extension of factorial to the complex numbers (including the reals.)

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the gamma function (with its argument shifted by $1$) isn't the only possible extension of the factorial. It is, however, by far the most often used one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The factorial function is extended by the $\Gamma$ function.  The relation is $$(n-1)! = \Gamma(n) = \int_0^\infty t^{n-1} e^{-t}\, dt$$
This can be analytically continued as a meromorphic function in the complex plane. Ref: John Conway's book on Complex Analysis.

Answer (score 2):

My favorite use of the factorial function for non-integer arguments is the formula for the volume of an $n$-dimensional ball of radius $r$:
$$
\frac{\pi^{n/2}r^n}{(n/2)!}.
$$

Comment: I'm just going to assume this is strictly about odd $n$, and you're not actually suggesting non-integral $n$, because the latter situation just broke my brain.

Comment: @Kevin Right; the dimension $n$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

As already noted by @ncmathsadist, the Gamma Function $$\Gamma(z)=(z-1)!$$ can be extended to a meromorphic function defined on the complex plane *without* the non-positive integers.

> Here's an instructive example how to work with *negative factorials* presented in [section $3.6$ of $A=B$](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568810636) by M. Petkovsek, H. Wilf and D. Zeilberger.
>
> **Challenge:** Find a closed expression for
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}t_k=\sum_{k}(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{4n-2k}{2n-k}
> \end{align*}

We start with checking if the ratio $\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_k}$ gives rise to a known *[hypergeometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)*. Indeed, with
\begin{align*}
\frac{t_{k+1}}{t_k}&=\frac{(-1)^{k+1}\binom{2n}{k+1}\binom{2k+2}{k+1}\binom{4n-2k-2}{2n-k-1}}
{(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{4n-2k}{2n-k}}
=\frac{(k+\frac{1}{2})(k-2n)^2}{(k+1)^2(k-2n+\frac{1}{2})}
\end{align*}
we derive
\begin{align*}
f(n)=\binom{4n}{2n} {}_{3}F_{2}\left(-2n,-2n,\frac{1}{2};1,-2n+\frac{1}{2};1\right)
\end{align*}

It turns out, that this hypergeometric series matches *[Dixon's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dixon%27s_identity)* and

> we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(n)=\binom{4n}{2n}\frac{(-n)!(-2n-\frac{1}{2})!(n-\frac{1}{2})}{(-2n)!n!(-n-\frac{1}{2})!(-\frac{1}{2})!}\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>
> At first glance this expression is rather distressing, since it contains factorials of *negative integers* which are precisely the values, where the gamma function is not defined!
>
> **The clou:** We have a *ratio* of two factorials at negative integers and if we can take an appropriate limit, the singularities will cancel leaving a pleasant limiting ratio. As the authors point out, this situation happens fairly frequently when using this approach.

$$$$

> We start analysing the ratio
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{(-n)!}{(-2n)!}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}

Let's assume, that $n$ is *near* a positive integer, but is not *equal to* a positive integer. Then we can use the *[reflection formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_formula)* for the $\Gamma$-function
\begin{align*}
\Gamma(z)\Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin \pi z}
\end{align*}
once more in the equivalent form
\begin{align*}
(-z)!=\frac{\pi}{(z-1)!\sin \pi z}
\end{align*}

> So, when $n$ is *near* a positive integer, the expression (2) becomes
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{(-n)!}{(-2n)!}=\frac{\pi}{(\sin n\pi)(n-1)!}\frac{(\sin 2n\pi)(2n-1)!}{\pi}=\frac{2(2n-1)!\cos n\pi}{(n-1)!}
> \end{align*}
>   and we observe, if $n$ approaches a positive integer
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{(-n)!}{(-2n)!}\longrightarrow(-1)^n\frac{(2n)!}{n!}
> \end{align*}
>   The expression (1) becomes
>   \begin{align*}
> f(n)=(-1)^n\binom{4n}{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{(-2n-\frac{1}{2})!(n-\frac{1}{2})}{(-n-\frac{1}{2})!(-\frac{1}{2})!}
> \end{align*}
>   Similarly, we find 
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{(-2n-\frac{1}{2})!}{(-n-\frac{1}{2})!}=\frac{(-1)^n(n-\frac{1}{2})!}{(2n-\frac{1}{2})!}
> \end{align*}
>   and we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> f(n)=\binom{4n}{2n}\binom{2n}{n}\frac{(n-\frac{1}{2})!^2}{(2n-\frac{1}{2})!(-\frac{1}{2})!}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}

For every positive integer $m$,
\begin{align*}
(m-\frac{1}{2})!&=(m-\frac{1}{2})(m-\frac{3}{2})\cdots(\frac{1}{2})(-\frac{1}{2})!\\
&=\frac{(2m-1)(2m-3)\cdots 1}{2^m}(-\frac{1}{2})!\\
&=\frac{(2m)!}{4^mm!}(-\frac{1}{2})!
\end{align*}

> This way we can simplify the expression (3) to $f(n)=\binom{2n}{n}^2$ and we have shown the identity
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{k}(-1)^k\binom{2n}{k}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{4n-2k}{2n-k}=\binom{2n}{n}^2
> \end{align*}