# Verify $f'(x) = e^x$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, power-series, taylor-expansion

The following is a proof I wrote to prove that given $f(x)=e^x$, $f'(x)=e^x$. For this proof we must use the Taylor Series for $e^x$, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$.

Since the derivative of a convergent power series is convergent on the same interval, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$ converges and is the power series for $\dfrac{d}{dx}[e^x]$.

Notably, $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n}}{n!}$. This final summation appears to be equal to $e^x$. Yet, I am concerned about its new index, $1$ to $\infty$. This implies that the first term of this new series is $x$, not $1$. Therefore, the new series cannot be equal to $e^x$.

What am I missing? (Thank you for your time.)

Comment: You would be better off using the limit definition of a derivative for this proof. It is not circular.

Comment: Using the Taylor series to prove the derivative for the e-power can only be done if you first discover the Taylor series for the e-power function without using any of the e-power function properties. I think there is a problem here...

Comment: here is wrong:$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{ \infty }\dfrac{x^{n}}{n!}$, in fact $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum\limits_{m=0}^{ \infty }\dfrac{x^m}{m!}$

Comment: @imranfat : I don't see how it is circular. with $\exp \overset{def}= \ln^{-1}$ and $\ln x \overset{def}= \int_1^x \frac{dt}{t}$ we can easily prove that $\ln xy = \ln x+\ln y$ (it's a logarithm) hence $\exp(x) = e^x$ is an exponentiation, and that $(e^x)' = (\ln^{-1} x)' = \frac{1}{\ln'(\ln^{-1}(x))} = \frac{1}{1 / \ln^{-1}(x)} = \ln^{-1}(x) = e^x$. finally since $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!} $ converges everywhere and is its own ($k$th !) derivative ( and is $1$ at $x=0$ ) then $e^x =  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!}$  (without the Taylor expansion theorem).

Comment: @LiJingyang : what is wrong is also writing $(-1)!$

Comment: @user1952009 I agree entirely with your steps from the ln set up to the e-power derived from the logarithm, but when it comes to rigor, your conclusion that the series is truly converging to the e-power it is not that obvious without Taylor expansion theorem. A little issue I am having is with the OP's statement saying "for the proof that [e^x]'=e^x we must (!!) use the Taylor series....No we must not...Verifying is somewhat different than a formal proof. At least that is of course my take on it.:)

Comment: @imranfat : do you want a full rigorous elementary proof that $f^{(k)}(0) = 1  \ \ \forall k\implies$ (locally) $f(x) = e^x$ ?

Comment: I admit it could be like proving a weak version of the Taylor expansion theorem (the version where all the derivatives at $x=0$ are of the same sign) hence quite circular here (I don't use the Taylor expansion theorem, but I prove it)

Comment: @user1952009. there is no need to use (-1)! since  the first term of  $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}$ is 1 (i.e when n=0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because $\dfrac{x^0}{0!}=1$ for any $x\neq 0$, the Taylor series is:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf e^x ~=~& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n!} \\[1ex] ~=~& 1+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^n}{n!}\end{align}$$

*Now* take the derivative with respect to $x$.

$$\begin{align}\dfrac{\operatorname d \mathsf e^x}{\operatorname d x} ~=~& 0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{n~x^{n-1}}{n!} \\[1ex] ~=~& \sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}\\[1ex] ~=~& \sum_{m=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^{m}}{(m)!} & : m=n-1\\[1ex] ~=~& \sum_{n=0}^\infty \dfrac{x^{n}}{n!} & : \alpha\textsf{-replacement} \\[2ex]\hline\therefore~~ \dfrac{\operatorname d \mathsf e^x}{\operatorname d x}  ~=~& \mathsf e^x & \Box\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but I think you've made two mistakes.
First, $$\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$ doesn't work when $n=0$.
Second, $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=-1}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Correct solution
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{nx^{n-1}}{n!}$$
$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$
$$=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: I think it does work. $\frac 1{-1!} =\frac 1\infty =0$.

Comment: @user202729 I found online a little more detail on negative factorials; I'm not entirely sure that's^ how it works.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1242602/how-do-you-find-the-factorial-of-a-decimal-or-negative-number-and-what-does-it-s